# How to put div tag and article tag in repeater control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm buiding a post status and comment page using HTML5 template. How can I put `<div>` tag and `<article>` tag in repeater control asp.net?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server"><div class="profile-stories">
    <article class="story" runat="server">
        <aside class="user-thumb">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/images/thumb-1.png" alt="" class="img-circle" />
            </a>
        </aside>
        <div class="story-content">
            <!-- story header -->
            <header>
                <div class="publisher">
                    <a href="#">Art Ramadani</a> posted a status update
                <em>3 hours ago</em>
                </div>
                <div class="story-type">
                    <i class="entypo-feather"></i>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="story-main-content">
                <p>Tolerably earnestly middleton extremely distrusts she boy now not. Add and offered prepare how cordial two promise. Greatly who affixed suppose but enquire compact prepare all put. Added forth chief trees but rooms think may. </p>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <!-- story comments -->
                <ul class="comments">
                    <li>
                        <div class="user-comment-thumb">
                            <img src="assets/images/thumb-1.png" alt="" class="img-circle" width="30" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-comment-content">
                            <a href="#" class="user-comment-name">Harold Bella
                            </a>
                            Mean if he they been no hold mr. Is at much do made took held help. Latter person am secure of estate genius at. 
                        <div class="user-comment-meta">
                            <a href="#" class="comment-date">January 2 at 3:25pm</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="comment-form">
                        <div class="user-comment-thumb">
                            <img src="assets/images/thumb-1.png" alt="" class="img-circle" width="30" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-comment-content" runat="server">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" CssClass="form-control autogrow" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnComment" CssClass="btn" Text='<i class="entypo-chat"></i>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
            <!-- separator -->
            <hr />
        </div>
    </article>
</div></asp:Repeater>
```

How can I solve this problem? If I cannot use repeater control how can I do so another way?

Answer (score 0):

The item that needs to be repeated should be wrapped in an ItemTemplate. If your outer div isn't something to be repeated, place the opening take in the HeaderTemplate and the closing tag in the FooterTemplate

More reading about that here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp